# Meteor: Error: {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values

Tags: debugging, meteor, console.log

I keep getting this error message when I click on the send button. Im trying to create a Instant Messenger app where online users can chat one on one. I am a beginner and I would really appreciate any help. Here is my error message, again it appears in the console once I click the Send button.

> Exception from Tracker recompute function: meteor.js:862 Error:
>   {{#each}} currently only accepts arrays, cursors or falsey values.
>       at badSequenceError (observe-sequence.js:148)
>       at observe-sequence.js:113
>       at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (tracker.js:597)
>       at observe-sequence.js:90
>       at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js:331)
>       at Tracker.Computation._recompute (tracker.js:350)
>       at Object.Tracker._runFlush (tracker.js:489)
>       at onGlobalMessage (meteor.js:347)

Here is my HTML

```
<template name="chat_page">
  <h2>Type in the box below to send a message!</h2>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="well well-lg">
        {{#each messages}}
          {{> chat_message}}
        {{/each}}
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form class="js-send-chat">
        <input class="input" type="text" name="chat" placeholder="type a message here...">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<!-- simple template that displays a message -->
<template name="chat_message">
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "row">
      <img src="/{{profile.avatar}}" class="avatar_img">
      {{username}} said: {{text}}
    </div>
  </div>  
  <br>
</template>
```

Client Side

```
Template.chat_page.helpers({
  messages: function () {
    var chat = Chats.findOne({ _id: Session.get("chatId") });
    return chat.messages;
  }, 
  other_user: function () {
    return "";
  }
});

Template.chat_page.events({
  'submit .js-send-chat': function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();
    var chat = Chats.findOne({ _id: Session.get("chatId") });
    if (chat) {
      var msgs = chat.messages; 
      if (! msgs) {
        msgs = [];
      }
      msgs.push({ text: event.target.chat.value });
      event.target.chat.value = "";
      chat.messages = msgs;
      Chats.update({ _id: chat._id }, { $set : { messages: chat } }); 
      Meteor.call("sendMessage", chat);
    }
  }
});
```

Parts of the server side

```
Meteor.publish("chats", function () { 
  return Chats.find(); 
});

Meteor.publish("userStatus", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({ "status.online": true });
});

Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({ _id: this.userId },{ fields: { 'other': 1, 'things': 1 } });
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
  return Meteor.users.find({ "status.online": true });
});

Meteor.publish("users", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({ "status.online": true });
});

Chats.allow({
  insert: function () { return true; },
  update: function () { return true; },
  remove: function () { return true; }
});

Meteor.methods({
  sendMessage: function (chat) {
    Chats.insert({
      chat: chat,
      createdAt: new Date(),
      username: Meteor.user().profile.username,
      avatar: Meteor.user().profile.avatar,
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the type of value stored in the field `messages`?

Comment: More specifically, is the type an array or a falsey value? As the error says, `{{#each}}` block accepts only arrays, cursors or falsey values. Since `messages` is a field in your chat document, you will be able to use `{{#each}}` on messages if its value is either an array or a falsey value.

Comment: hmmm I understand what you're saying. Messages should show each message sent by the user(chat_message).From my understanding, messages should show each chat_message as an array. Can a mistake  in the chat_message template cause it not to insert correctly? Causing the #each not to read correctly.

Comment: I don't think a mistake in template `chat_message` would throw the error that you have reported. The error is specifically in the line `{{#each messages}}` as it is not getting a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your subscriptions aren't ready. This means that `Chats.findOne()` will return nothing, meaning that `Chats.findOne().messages` will be undefined.

Try the following:

```
{{ #if Template.subscriptionsReady }}
  {{#each messages}}
  {{/each}}
{{/else}}
```

Alternatively, use a `find()` on chats, then `{{#each}}` on the messages within that chat. For example:

```
Template['Chat'].helpers({
  chats: function () {
    return Chats.find(Session.get('chatId')); // _id is unique, so this should only ever have one result.
  }
});
```

Then in template:

```
{{#each chats}}
  {{#each messages}}
    {{>chat_message}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: If subscriptions aren't ready, won't `Chats.findOne()` be undefined and accessing `Chats.findOne().messages` give a `Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined` error instead of the error that the OP reported?

Comment: Also, even if Chats.findOne().messages is undefined, it still does not explain the error as undefined being a falsey value is a valid value as far as `{{#each}}` block is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a logical error in this line

```
Chats.update({ _id : chat._id }, { $set : { messages : chat } });
```

You are setting the value of the field `messages` to `chat`. But `chat` is an object. So in your helper when you are returning `Chats.findOne().messages` to the `{{#each}}` block, you are actually returning an object which is not a valid value to be sent to an `{{#each}}` block and hence the error.

I think what you mean to do is

```
Chats.update({ _id : chat._id }, { $set : { messages : msgs } });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That did work, as far as removing the error but my messages are still not appearing but when I route to the main I get another error and I believe this is what is stopping the messages from appearing.

Comment: Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined

Comment: I see. In your `messages` helper, try replacing the line `return chat.messages;` with `return chat && chat.messages;`.

Comment: Definitively helped with the error, thank you. Im still having issues with the actual messages appearing. Once I click send nothing appears. No errors but nothing appears either. I want you to know I thank you for your help so much.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I figured it out. I forgot to publish and subscribe the messages. Thank you again for all your help!!

Comment: Great. Glad to be of help (at least with your initial problem). You can accept the answer if it helped you as other programmers looking up this question may find it useful.